# DVIHDMI to network stream (mms, etc.)

Tags: hdmi, dvi, video-streaming

Did anybody ever hear or use appliance which has HDMI/DVI input (like monitor) and can broadcast network stream (mms, etc.)? So, the goal is obviously to plug it to PC graphic card (DVI/HDMI) and broadcast incoming signal to network as a stream (like mms)

Comment: Never heard of anything like this. If at all, you'll find something like this in professional/broadcasting quality only.

Answer (score 0):

As slhck says you're probably not going to find a (reasonably priced, or easily available) stand-alone appliance to do this.

You could probably get away with using a PC with an HDMI capture card [like one of these](http://www.blackmagic-design.com/products/intensity/models/), and then stream that using [Windows Media Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Services) (or alike).